# The speed of Yarn search packages

Tags: javascript, search, web, package, yarnpkg

Anyone know how did yarn site do the coding in the search bar for packages? And why it shows the result so lightning fast?

You can try searching anything and notice how quick can it displays the results: https://yarnpkg.com/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into my Network tab of the Web Inspector, they make a call to Algolia, a service providing a search engine.

Every character you type immediately causes a query to be sent to this service. For more info: https://www.algolia.com

Comment: Yes. Thanks Jeff. I thought there's no third party service involved.